# Copy-Item: Illegal characters in path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that will copy files from a source to the same path on multiple destination machines.  I found this on the web and have pointed toward my test data, however, I continue to receive the following error (for each system it finds in the pc_list.txt).

Script:

```
$Computers = gc "C:\Temp\Script\PC_List.txt"
$Source = "C:\Temp\Script\AAAAA.txt"
$Destination = "C$\Temp\"
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination "\\$Computer\$Destination\" -Recurse
}
```

Error:

```
Copy-Item : Illegal characters in path.
At line:4 char:36
    + ... Computers) {Copy-Item $Source -Destination "\\$Computer\$Destination\ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

PC Names in PC_List.txt:

```
DEPT-PC1
DEPT-PC2
DEPT-PC3
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Any blank lines in your txt file?

Comment: Adding to @BenH's comment: It's conceptually cleaner (though not strictly necessary) to escape the `$` in `"C$\Temp\"` with a backtick. Similarly, the `\ ` at the end of `"\\$Computer\$Destination\"` means that your path ends in `\\ ` (again, no real harm). Apart from that there's no obvious problem with your code. See if `-WhatIf` applied to `Copy-Item` reveals anything.

Comment: No blank lines, I’ll try the WhatIf in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

BenH is correct. While I did not have any blank lines in the PC_List.txt, I did have a space at the end of each line...  Great catch!!!

Now I’m getting “The target account name is incorrect”.

I’m thinking I’m going to need to add a $session credentials line but will need to figure out how to implement that piece...

Comment: Do you have WinRM(PSRemoting) enabled in your environment?

Comment: Yes.  I have activated it through GPO.  Should I not have to do a New-PSSession if WinRM is enabled?

Comment: So I've got the New-PSSession working I believe, however I have now found that my script is placing the last entry in my PC List in each Copy-Item Path...    e.g.  Copy-Item : The path '\\Dept-PC1\\\Dept-PC3\C$\Temp\' is not valid. Only absolute paths are supported on remote copy operations.

Comment: So what is your end goal? Copying from one device to another that is not the host you're on?

Comment: My end goal is this:   We have a software vendor that requires config files to be copied to the same folder on all of the systems that their software is on.  Instead of manually getting into each pc \\Dept-PC1 I would like to run a PS script that copies the file / files to all PC’s in the list immediately.

Comment: When you use sessions, the parameters become local to that session so -Path $path -Destination $destination with -ToSession and -FromSession no longer need to qualify the smb share. Use the local c:\whatever path